# Installing Laravel on DigitalOcean error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I've tried to install Laravel on a VPS, but I got an error in "bootstrap/compiled.php":

> file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 197 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space

I'm using the LAMP stack, installing via `composer create-project`. I followed these steps:

- Install via `composer create-project`
- Set permissions and user group:

  - `chgrp -R www-data myproject`
  - `chmod -R 775 myproject/app/storage`

After these still getting the error. With some trying, services.json will be created but it's became empty and laravel can't write in it.

What is missing?

Comment: What error exactly did you get? (I'd say, in any case, you don't need to "install" Laravel on your host. The usual workflow is to create a local PHP project, import Laravel into it via Composer, and then deploy the whole project to your server. The deployment can be via VCS, rsync, scp, FTP, or a dedicated deployment tool.)

Comment: In bootstrap/compiled.php: **file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 197 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space**
I tried a clean install, that why i tried to use **composer create-project..**

I've read a tons of questions and answers here in SO, but none of them works for me.

Comment: Ok getting closer: services.json generated, owned by www-data. Permission are: -rw-r--r--. If I change it to 775, the next problem appears: **array_merge error in bootstrap/compiled.php** - due the services.json is totally empty. If I remove this file and let laravel create again, it will be created with permissions above. Is there any with www-data permissions?

Comment: I've not used Laravel, nor Digital Ocean, so can't say. But I still think you're doing it wrong: once Laravel is installed on a remote host, it won't _do_ anything. It needs to be brought into an app, which is best developed locally.

Comment: Who owns the daily created log under `storage/logs`? If it's `root`, it *can* be your problem.